# Differential equation involving inverse function theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Pardon me if you find the question crazy.

How do we solve the differential equation,

$$\frac{df^{-1}(t)}{dt} \Biggm |_{f(t)} = \frac{1}{f(t)(1-f(t))}$$.

**without** using the following approach:

If we multiply LHS and RHS by $df$, by inverse function theorem we have for LHS,
$$ \frac{df^{-1}(t)}{dt}  \Biggm |_{f(t)} df = dt $$

And thus,

$$ \frac{df}{dt} = f(t)(1-f(t))$$ and we can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the notation $$\frac{df^{-1}(t)}{dt}\lvert_{f(t)}$$ means $$\frac{df^{-1}(f(t))}{df(t)}=\frac{dt}{df(t)}$$

So we obtain
$$\frac{dt}{df}=\frac{1}{f\cdot(1-f)}$$
which is separable: $$dt=\frac{df}{f\cdot(1-f)}\implies t+C=\ln|f\cdot(1-f)|$$

Comment: Well isn't the notation $$\frac{df^{-1}(t)}{dt} \Biggm |_{f(t)}$$ mean first taking the derivative with respect to $t$ and substituting $f(t)$ than just substituting like what you did?